# Comparison parameters are not working fine

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following comparison parameter for one of my script:

```
$FreeSpace -lt 5550
```

The result should be `true`, but it displays `false`. Considering that `$FreeSpace` value is only `600`.

Is it normal to face such a behavior?

Comment: What is the type of your `$FreeSpace` variable?  I suspect you're comparing an integer to a string.  Check: `$FreeSpace.GetType().FullName`

Comment: yes, it is a string

Comment: `$FreeSpace` -> `([int]$FreeSpace)`. [Related](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is comparing a string to an integer.  The operator will try converting this, but it's not going to be what you expect with strings.  If you cast the types to match, you should get the expected result:

```
> $FreeSpace = '600'
> [int]$FreeSpace -lt 5550
>> True
```